# Warning: URL "https://instantappmodule.firebaseapp.com/" not defined in the manifest

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest, android-instant-apps

I am making a sample instant app but without introducing app bundles and dynamic-feature's. I am quite close except that I am getting this error on the configuration: Warning: URL "https://instantappmodule.firebaseapp.com/" not defined in the manifest.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.instantappmodule"
android:targetSandboxVersion="1">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="InstantMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="instantappmodule.firebaseapp.com/"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is you may not have added the following 2 lines of code:

Comment: I believe you forgot to paste the lines.

Answer (score 0):

It should be defined as:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:host="instantappmodule.firebaseapp.com/"
            android:scheme="https" />
        <data
            android:host="instantappmodule.firebaseapp.com/"
            android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: can you verify it by changing host to something else, like: instantappmodule.com

Comment: Whatever the url was I would get the same warning